# Userid, formid, and caseid- any logic to how they are generated?

Tags: commcare

Is there any logic behind the CommCare ids that are automatically generated? What I mean is, does the id always include a certain combination of letters or numbers, such as 8 numbers and then 2 letters?

Answer (score 1):

CommCare's internal ID's for cases, form id's, etc are random [UUID V4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) GUID's, in practice, but the specifications we follow don't guarantee anything other than that they should be "Globally Unique".

This means they should be unique across devices and platforms without the need for an online central uniqueness issuer, but nothing else about them can really be guaranteed.